# Error opening emulator from device selection dropdown

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I open emulator form device selection dropdown I have the following error, If I run it from AVD manager no error happens
How can I fix this?

```
emulator: WARNING: FeatureControlImpl.cpp:198: Failed to load advanced feature default setting:C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\advancedFeaturesCanary.ini emulator: WARNING: encryption is off Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go to the location showing in the Error Box, and after Sdk folder u will find folder name **emulator** & **emulator-2** , in that case just delete emulator folder and rename **emulator-2** to **emulator**.

Comment: It works, why folder `emulator-2` exists, What's wrong here?

Comment: @WebMaster, `emulator-2` is the latest, `emulator` is the obsolete

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the Android-Studio Emulator might not have been installed properly. Go to the AVD Manager window and a message saying "Emulator not installed" will be clearly visible. If that's the case, just install the Emulator(You might get a button or pop up for that there itself) & you will be good to go!

Comment: No, It is installed and I can run it from AVD manager, I also delete and re-install emulator, same issue

Answer (score 1):

in VS code >>>the solution is Go for **settings> Extension > Android Emulator Launcher Configuration**   then find your emulator path then copy it then paste it in the two boxes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSw28.png)